# invalid cast to type 'float'

Tags: c++, conversion-operator, comparison-operators

I'm having problem with my class. I'm going to make comparision operators of my class.
Some code:

```
CVariable::operator float ()
{
    float rt = 0;
    std::istringstream Ss (m_value);
    Ss >> rt;
    return rt;
};

bool CVariable::operator < (const CVariable& other)
{
    if (m_type == STRING || other.Type() == STRING)
        int i = 0; // placeholder for error handling
    else
        return (float) *this < (float) other;
};
```

Class declaration:

```
class CVariable
{
    public:
    inline VARTYPE Type () const {return m_type;};
    inline const std::string& Value () const {return m_value;};
    bool SetType (VARTYPE);

    private:
     int m_flags;
    VARTYPE m_type;
    std::string m_value;

    public:

    // ...


    operator int ();
    operator float ();
    operator std::string ();

    //...


    inline bool operator == (const CVariable& other) {return m_value == other.Value();};
    inline bool operator != (const CVariable& other) {return m_value != other.Value();};
    bool operator < (const CVariable&);
```

The problem is, I've got compile error in operator < function, on this line:

```
return (float) *this < (float) other;
```

Properly in part: (float) other

The error message is:

```
cvariable.cpp|142|error: invalid cast from type 'const MCXJS::CVariable' to type 'float'|
```

What's the cause of problem?

Comment: While you're fixing your code, consider using `static_cast<float>(*this)` instead of C-style `(float) *this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conversion operator is non-const but the object `other` refers to is const-qualified. You have to add `const` to the conversion operators like this:

```
operator int () const;
operator float () const;
operator std::string () const;
```

This `const` also needs to be added to the definitions.

Comment: +1 You beat me to my answer. (The other posters should delete theirs like I did mine. Late answers usually get no upvotes.)

Answer (score 0):

a pure guess. You float operator is not const

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko this is in fact the correct answer - so how is it not an answer. Would it be OK if I left off the words "A pure guess"